# Batch file to enable/disable network adapter

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd

I've got a script that is useful at work to change our LAN adapter Static/DHCP which works fine. However, we do need to occasionally disable our network adapter when using commands over the network (in case of conflict on different networks).
This is the code that I've got for the enable/disable commands.

```
:2
@echo off
netsh wlan show networks | FIND "Wireless network connection" /I /C >NUL 2>NUL
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 (netsh interface set interface "Wireless network connection" DISABLED)
IF %errorlevel% equ 0 (netsh interface set interface "Wireless network connection" ENABLED)
exit /b
```

When I run the netsh commands separately do execute correctly, meaning there's an issue with my if statement.

When the network adapter is enabled:

```
netsh wlan show networks | FIND "Wireless network connection" /I /C
1
```

When the network adapter is disabled:

```
netsh wlan show networks | FIND "Wireless network connection" /I /C
0
```

When running the entire code, each run through (regardless of the state of the wireless network adapter, returns 1).
Any suggestions guys?

Comment: may it break with `'stdout' is not recognized...`?

Comment: Ah that was left in from a different test on the code. Edited out.
Would there have been any other issue with the code?

Comment: try setting a variable equal to `%errorlevel%` before executing another command and test on that in your `if`.

Comment: I suppose this is not part of IF or FOR condition based on the `:2` at the beginning

Comment: Setting a variable to equal %errorlevel% didn't seem to have any effect.
I'm assuming I was meant to change the if to check against the variable, rather than *errorlevel%

Comment: The :2 refers to a choice the user has to disable/enable the Wireless network adapter, instead of the LAN adapter.

Comment: try executing your batch-file as administrator, and executing the batch-file from cmd, so you can see the errormessage it gives.

Comment: I've been running it through cmd, but there aren't any error messages.
I have :: out the >nul and 2>nul commands which has successfully caused the network adapter to be disabled, but re-running it doesn't turn the adapter back on?

Answer (score 0):

```
echo Errorlevel was %errorlevel%
IF %errorlevel% equ 1 (
 echo was enabled
 netsh interface set interface "Wireless network connection" DISABLED
) else (
 echo was disabled
 IF %errorlevel% equ 0 (
   netsh interface set interface "Wireless network connection" ENABLED
 )
)
```

As you currently have it, the second `errorlevel` will interpret the results of the first `netsh` if that is effected.

Comment: Added your changes and there still doesn't seem to be any noticeable change.

Comment: Perhaps yu could reveal what effect you are observing that you did not expect.

Comment: Well from change adapter settings, I would expect the wireless network adapter to either be disabled if previously enabled, or vice versa.

Comment: Since we can't look over your shoulder too easily, perhaps you could post the response of the initial `netsh` with the adaptor enabled and again disabled?

Comment: Edited in the outputs

Comment: Every execution now just returns 1.

Answer (score 0):

don't confuse command output and `%errorlevel%`:

```
C:> echo yes|find "yes" /c
1

C:> echo %errorlevel%
0

C:> echo yes|find "no" /c
0

C:> echo %errorlevel%
1
```

`%errorlevel%` is set, when the last command (`find`) was unsuccessful, while `find /c` returns the count of findings. No findings means `find /c` returns `0` and an `%errorlevel%` of 1.

Comment: Ah thank you Stephan for clarifying my glaring misunderstanding!!